# VSCode Svelte autocomplete for dot notation components

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, svelte

I am building a svelte component library that utilizes dot notation for component composition. I have dot notation working as it should but when I type a `.` instead of showing only the possible child components it acts like I just typed a `<` and started a new tag. I have the following `<Button />` component:

```
import OriginalButton from './Button.svelte';
import Icon from './Icon.svelte';

const Button = OriginalButton as ButtonStatic;
Button.Icon = Icon;
Button.Leading = Icon;
Button.Trailing = Icon;

export default Button;

export interface ButtonStatic {
    new (...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof OriginalButton>): OriginalButton;
    Icon: typeof Icon;
    Leading: typeof Icon;
    Trailing: typeof Icon;
}
```

When I type `<Button.` I would like autocomplete/intellisense to show me `Icon`, `Leading`, or `Trailing` but instead it is showing me all available components.

[image]

Is this something that can be done in VSCode settings or do I need to create an extension?

Comment: I would open an issue [in the `language-tools` repository](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues) and ask whether that could be supported, since it works correctly at run-time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have opened an issue there as well. https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/1701